# SOLVED Install Webmin on Bullseye RPi 4B

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, docker, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, repository

I'm trying to install Webmin on raspberryOS bullseye 32bits (5.10.87-v7l+ kernel), and the installation get stuck on: "Unpacking webmin (1.983) ..."

I already try to install over 2 methods:

1. Adding "deb https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge
   contrib" to "/etc/apt/sources.list"
2. wget https://download.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
3. apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
4. apt-get install Webmin

And 2nd method:

1. wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.983_all.deb
2. dpkg --install webmin_1.983_all.deb

Both get exactly the same result.
I try to install an old version (v1.920) over dpkg, I reach the end of installation with success. But when I try to upgrade in the webUI for v1.983 (because of security issues), I end with the same result: crash and I get a error:

```
Error. 500 - Perl execution failed - Undefined subroutine &main::authentic called
```

If I refresh the WebUI I get:

```
Error - Perl execution failed

Undefined subroutine &WebminCore::theme_get_webprefix_local called at /usr/share/webmin/authentic-theme/authentic.pl line 1311. Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/webmin/webmin/upgrade.cgi line 5.
```

Later the only way to remove it from system is using:

$ dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq webmin

Also I try to use apt to do the installation, and check the progress, but after 1 hour still stuck at 20%:

```
$ sudo apt install ./webmin_1.983_all.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'webmin' instead of './webmin_1.983_all.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  webmin

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/28.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 302 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/pi/webmin_1.983_all.deb webmin all 1.983 [28.1 MB]
(Reading database ... 100909 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /home/pi/webmin_1.983_all.deb ...
Unpacking webmin (1.983) ...

Progress: [ 20%] [###########...............................................]
```

Anyone facing the same problem with bullseye? There is another way to install it, like docker/portainer instead?

Comment: `get stuck on: "Unpacking webmin (1.983) ..."` ... just trying this on a pi3 (so, a bit solwer than a pi4) ... it took about 5 minutes ... have you tried using some patience?

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of the user Bravo, I left installing during a half a hour, take a coffee and come back, and was done! Installed with success!

I guess the best explanation for this RPi 4 (4Gb) it's using an old SATA 2.5 1Tb hard drive 5400 rpm as a main and boot drive over USB3, is about 10 years old and probably high fragmented (S.M.A.R.T. already show me some red flags) and took much more time... than a SD.

Also this thread it's 30 days old, maybe some OS update could make this work today.